# Tensor of zeros with known or unknown dimension

Tags: python, tensor, dimension

I am new of Python, I want to create a tensor of zeros with a certain dimension, how can i do that? I don't want to obtain necessary a matrix but instead something with higher dimensions.
Is it possible to realize a tensor with an arbitrary diemsion?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use numpy.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.zeros((10,100))

b= np.random.random((50,600))

c = np.zeros_like(b)
```

as you can see

```
np.zeros((your dimention))
```

and you can create tensor of zeros from variables dimention

```
np.zeros_like(b)
```

we can see that

```
print(c.shape)
```

same shape that b variable has

```
(50,600)
```